# How to add a Navigation Page in Master Detail Page?

Tags: listview, xamarin

I am a newbie. I would like to use Xamarin to design an app which the main menu will be used Master Detail Page,and in one of the detail pages will be shown a Listview (with detail page from the list view). I am struggling how to do that?

Am I need to use Navigation Page to include a list view? How to add a Navigation Page in the Master Detail Page?

It is hard to find the code sample for this layout, many thanks for your help!!!


My ideal workflow are as follows:
1. My main menu will use Master Detail Page >>
2. One of the menu will show the list view >>
3. When the user click the list view, it will show the detail page.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I need to use Navigation Page to include a list view? How to add a Navigation Page in the Master Detail Page?

Use the code below to navigate to the details page of `listview` in `OnItemSelected` event.

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItemDetailPage(new ItemDetailViewModel(item)));
```

`ItemDetailPage` is detail page of listview.
`ItemDetailViewModel` is the view model of listview detail page.
`Item` is the selected value of listview.

[image]

You could download from the GitHub in MasterDetailPageTemplate folder.
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

An easy way is to select the Master-Detail template when you create the Xamarin.forms project.

[image]